# Unable to add header in firefox os

Tags: firefox-os

I am unable to add a header in my app for firefox os the code that i used is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Hindie</title>
    <script src="/js/action.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/webapp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/offline.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/headers.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/buttons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/toolbars.css">
</head>
<body >
  <section role="region">
      <header>
        <button><span class="icon icon-close">close</span></button>
        <menu type="toolbar"><button>done</button></menu>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>
    </section>
    <div id="main">
```

I ran the same in simulator but am only getting an small orange rectangle on top left corner of my app

Comment: It's hard to tell without the CSS as it's probably where the problem is. Can you publish it, so we can check where the problem is?

Comment: ok the main style sheet is [style.css](http://snipt.org/BwI7) and the main html [Index.html](http://snipt.org/BwI7)

Comment: The link for index.html isn't the good one (it's the CSS one, again).

Comment: Sorry for that this is the new one [Index.html](http://snipt.org/Bwic7)

Answer (score 1):

please retire "/"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/headers.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/buttons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/toolbars.css">
```

Comment: Think that's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any problem: you may not have put the right CSS file online as there is no orange in it. I added

```
header {
    background-color: #FFA500;
}
```

to your CSS file, and I'm seeing a large orange rectangle (with some margins) in the browser as in the Firefox OS simulator. If you don't want the margin, add

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```